# TCP listener stops listening

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, windows-services

We currently have a TCP Listener hosted in a windows service.  It appears to stop listening at some random interval and, obviously, when a client subsequently makes a request it gets refused. I have tried taking all the Tasks out and the problem still persists. No exception is thrown and consequently nothing is written to the Event Log.

```
public void Run()
{
    var tcpDetail = Task.Run(() => _settingsHelper.GetTcpDetail());

    if (tcpDetail != null)
    {
        var listener = new TcpListener(tcpDetail.Result.ListeningAddress, tcpDetail.Result.ListeningPort);

        listener.Start();

       while (true)
        {
            var tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            try
            {
                Task.Run(() => ProcessClient(tcpClient));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, ex.Message);
                if (tcpClient.Client != null && tcpClient.Connected)
                {
                    tcpClient.Close();
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
}


 private void ProcessClient(TcpClient client)
{
    try
    {
        var networkStream = client.GetStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);


        var networkStream = client.GetStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

        var request = reader.ReadToEnd();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
        {
            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(request);
            _someService.Execute(xmlDocument);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, ex.Message);
        if (client.Client != null && client.Connected)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (client.Client != null && client.Connected)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this behaviour was occurring due to the service being restarted and I was stopping the listening.  Making a call to stopping the listener in the OnStop function solved the issue.